# Why is targetframework "net6" and "net7" allowed?

Tags: c#, .net

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) Microsoft documentation, the targetframework can be set to the following:

[image]

In my csproj files, I have several references to "net6" and "net7":

[image]

This seems to work just fine. I don't see any references to this formatting in the documentation though. Two questions:

1. Why does this work?
2. Should I change these references to "net6.0" and "net7.0"?

Comment: I don't think anyone but MS can tell you exactly why it's allowed. However with .Net Core+ it seems like the paradigm has moved from exact settings to gracious fallbacks. Which of the paradigms is best depends on who you ask :) My best guess is that answer to you question will be "Because MS decided that was the best approach". Personally, I would change it to 6.0/7.0 to be more explicit.

Comment: [Will work, but shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/net5/net5.md)

Comment: Thanks Hans, guess I'll update to 7.0 whereever I see it being used.

Comment: @HansPassant It took a bit of digging to find the specific bit you were talking about under [What about .NET 10?](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/net5/net5.md#what-about-net-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant in the comments I figured out it's an alias, but you should use net7.0 and net6.0.

https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/net5/net5.md#what-about-net-10

[image]

As you can see `net10` is not .NETCoreApp 10.0 as expected but .NET Framework 1.0 instead.