# Is the `net6` (not `net6.0`) is a valid target framework value?

Tags: c#, .net, csproj

Some times I see the projects with target framework set to the `net6` (not `net6.0`) in its 'csproj' files.

```
    <TargetFrameworks>net6-macos;net6-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

Such a projects builds and works without problems.
At the same time [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) lists only `net6.0`-like values as a valid for the target framework in sdk-style projects.

So, the question is: does `net6` tfm works by accident or it's a valid value by design? Should the usage of `net6` be considered as a bug and fixed to the `net6.0`?

Comment: I can't find anywhere in documentation that allows the usage of `net6`, so I would consider that, although it could work, it should not be used since it may break in the future.

Comment: It is the same. net6 translates still to net6.0. So, it's up to you.

Comment: Besides the point if it is valid syntax. Microsoft has released minor updates 2.1 2.2 3.1 and those where big changes you would not want to update silent.

Comment: @Taco I believe that if `net6` is valid, it should be equivalent to the `net6.0` and silent misinterpretation as `net6.1` or something like this should not be possible.

Comment: Not quite true, framework-dependet apps (even with `net6.0` moniker) will roll forward if the target framework is not found at runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward But as I said, even in this documentation, `net6` is not mentioned as a valid TFM

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652005/why-is-targetframework-net6-and-net7-allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As conclusion: there is no any  evidences that `net6` is a valid tfm by design.

Moreover, some tooling unable to work correctly with such a tfm. For example, VS for Mac will throw "Error updating Objective-C type information" error when trying to edit xib/storyboard in the project where there is incorrect tfm somewhere in the dependencies tree ([community report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-updating-Objective-C-type-informa/10311098?sort=newest)).

So, it's better to treat `net6` tfm as an error and fix it with `net6.0` to avoid some very unpredictable and surprising effects in some use cases.